# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preshed==2.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, version, spacy

I am trying to install spaCy on Windows. I am running python 3.6.  When I run

`pip install -U spacy`

I get the following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/simple/
Collecting spacy
  Downloading https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi                              /packages/spacy/2.1.4/spacy-2.1.4.tar.gz (29.8MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\fast\python\3.6.4\python.exe' 'c:\fast\python\3.6.4\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\r419957\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8u72uukr\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/simple/ -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6:
  ERROR: Looking in indexes: https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/simple/
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/packages/setuptools/41.0.1/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (575kB)
  Collecting wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0
    Downloading https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/packages/wheel/0.33.4/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Downloading https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/packages/Cython/0.29.2/Cython-0.29.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (1.6MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Downloading https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/packages/cymem/2.0.2/cymem-2.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\fast\python\3.6.4\python.exe' 'c:\fast\python\3.6.4\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\r419957\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8u72uukr\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://my-artifact-repo.com/artifactory/api/pypi/public-pypi/simple/ -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I then tried to download preshed by itself by running

`pip install preshed`

This however does not install the version I need which is 2.0.1

When I run

`pip install preshed==2.0.1`

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preshed==2.0.1 (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for preshed==2.0.1
```

Any help figuring out what is going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `pip` set up to look for packages in your private repository (`my-artifact-repo.com`) which is missing the package. Either upload the `preshed` package (and its eventual dependencies) to the private repo, or install `preshed` from PyPI:

```
$ pip install preshed --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/
```